# Rules for combining sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositional-phrases

1)-Thank you very much for accepting my request for taking care of my home during my absence.

2)-Thank you very much for accepting my request taking care of my home during my absence.

Or

3)-Thank you very much for accepting my request in taking care of my home during my absence.

The confusion is related to combining sentences with prepositional, participle or noun phrases. Either it should be in taking care...., for taking care...., or just taking care...?

which sentence example is grammatically correct and why others are not?

Regards;

Answer (score 1):

For non-natives like you and me, it is difficult to pick up a correct preposition. I understand!

Well, in such case, *dictionaries* are the only resort! The *bothering verb* here is 'request.' That's it. Jump on to the dictionary and check which **preposition** that verb has taken in the entries.

Cambridge is what I prefer because the **bold** prepositions! The verb ['request' takes *for, to, at, and on.*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/request)

Check what suits in your example. It is *to*.

> *Thank you very much for accepting my request <del>in</del> **to** take care of my home during my absence.*